# Inner join on two tables in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, inner-join

I have 2 entities and want to perform an inner join on the ID of these two tables. How do I do that? After joining the tables, how do I get the values?

First entity: `Employee.java`

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "emp")
    public class Employee {
    @Id

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "language", nullable = false)
    private String language;
```

Second entity: `Username.java`

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users") 
    public class Username {
    @Id

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's helpful for your or not but,

You have to give relationship between those table first(Here i defined bidirectional relationship). 
I suppose there is @OneToOne mapping. As like follow,
In Employee Table,

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "username_id")
private Username username;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
private Employee employee;
```

Same way whenever you need those data base on requirement then Place Query as following way in your Employee Repository,

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="<your-join-query>")
public Employee getEmployeeAllDetails();
```

For more brief detail follow this kind of tutorials which give you better idea regurding working mechenisum.

https://howtodoinjava.com/

https://www.baeldung.com/